# How can I efficiently make a solid Texture2D?

Tags: unity, textures, gui, pixel, per-pixel

I am trying to programmatically make an `Image` to cover the entire screen.  I create the Texture2D, then create a Sprite from the `Texture2D`, then apply the `Sprite` to my `Image`. This works, but it is slow.

I suspect the issue is that I am setting each pixel individually for my `Texture2D`:

```
private static Texture2D CreateSolidTexture2D(Color color)
{
    var texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
        {
            texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    texture.Apply();
    return texture;
}
```

I have tried creating the `Texture2D` by resizing a `Texture2D` of a single pixel, but the color comes out as a translucent white, instead of the color passed:

```
private static Texture2D CreateSolidTexture2D(Color color)
{
    var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
    texture.Resize(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    texture.Apply();
    return texture;
}
```

Why doesn't my second approach work?  How can I *efficiently* create a screen-sized `Texture2D` of a solid color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of texture.SetPixel, use [`texture.SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html)

```
var texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
Color[] pixels = Enumerable.Repeat(color, Screen.width * Screen.height).ToArray();
texture.SetPixels(pixels);
texture.Apply();
return texture;
```

Using [`texture.LoadRawTextureData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) might be even faster, but this requires that you know more about your texture format.

Alternatively you could use the hard-coded [`Texture2D.whiteTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D-whiteTexture.html), stretch it to the size of the screen and set the color through the shader (this is what I would really recommend you to do if you plan to show a lot of different colors in quick succession).

Comment: I tried Texture2D.blackTexture and resized it, but I had the same result of the translucent white color.  The Linq option presented is much faster though.  Thank you!